# Should a post-workout protein shake count in my macros?

Tags: diet, nutrition

I'm in the process of creating a new diet plan with http://www.eatthismuch.com/ however I'm unsure with workout days if I should be intentionally eating less calories to account for the ones I'm consuming with my post-workout protein shake. How do people normally do this? Do they discount the shake or do they simply adjust their meal plans accordingly to account for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shake is food; you're eating it. If you're trying to maintain a certain daily calorie level (e.g., maintain a specific deficit for weight loss, or surplus for gain) then *both* the shake and exercise must be counted.